# Applying CSS to Sidebar's Last Block Element in Responsive Design

Tags: css, fonts

I was looking for a way to apply smaller font size to sidebar content. For that I did `#sidebar { font-size: 85%}`. It applied smaller font size to sidebar content. But then I used `h4` for sidebar header and that is already small so I thought not to apply smaller to that.

For the above thought I searched for any wrapper container for Wordpress widget content or any class that is available in all widget content but could not find any good solution. One solution only worked for text widget which is not useful. So, tried CSS solution:

CSS selector I tried:

1

```
.widget :not([class~=sideheader]) {}
```

2.

```
.widget :last-child {}
```

Above it seems apply per cent font-size in different way. It is cascading from somewhere and font size applied is much smaller than I used (85%). When I use #sidebar or particular widget content class (`.related-widget {}`) then it works perfectly.

**My question is**: Why it is cascading to much lower font-size whereas I have not applied any font-size on their any parent? I have removed `#sidebar {--smaller--}` before trying this. Font is only applied to `body {}`.

Comment: Check the computed font size of each element prior to applying the percentage. 85% of whichever absolute font size will always be the same value if both elements have the same computed font size.

Comment: Though this is working but I understand this all selector (*) solution is very bad for performance !

    `.sideheader + * {
        .smaller;
    }`

Comment: @JamesDonnelly There is no problem in font-size in comparison to different element of sidebar. I wanted to apply smaller font only to widget content area and not header.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is not directly related but I used one of the solution [here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/121564/how-to-add-wrapper-div-container-element-around-wordpress-widget-content) for WordPress and solved this. That is adding extra div in before_widget and after_widget.